# SQL Server User roles that have roles inside them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, roles, members

I know the title might be a bit confusing, but that was the best I could came up with. 
So here is my question: I have a DB that has many roles, some of these roles have as a role member other roles, so when a users is added into a role it will automatically add that users to other roles as well.

For exameple in my db if I run the SQL  :

`exec sp_helprolemember op_ConfigDefault` -- this will give me all the members of the op_ConfigDefault role. Inside these role some of the members are infact roles. I made some print screen to be more clear 
[image]

Here in the blue squere I have the members with are  roles and in the red square are normal users.

[image]

Here you can see those "member" from above are indeed roles.

My question now is, is there a way I could build a T-SQL so I can get only the Members from a role that are also roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've mananaged to find the solution

```
SELECT DbRole = g.NAME,
    MemberName = u.NAME,
    MemberSID = u.sid
FROM sys.database_principals u,
    sys.database_principals g,
    sys.database_role_members m
WHERE g.NAME = /* add role name here*/
    AND g.principal_id = m.role_principal_id
    AND u.principal_id = m.member_principal_id
    AND u.NAME IN (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM sys.database_principals
        WHERE type = 'R'
        )
ORDER BY 1, 2
```